# Prove a relation is a equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $\sim$ be defined so that $a\sim b$ when $a+b$ is even.  Is this an equivalence relation?

Equivalence relations confuse me a lot, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: An equivalence relation *on which set*?

Comment: The question doesn't specify.

Comment: I'd guess the context of the question (which you also omitted) implies some set. Presumably $\mathbb N$ or $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- $a+a=2a$ even so $a\sim a$
- If $a\sim b$ so $a+b=b+a$ is even so $b\sim a$
- If $a\sim b$ and $b\sim c$ then $a+b$ and $b+c$ are even so $a+2b+c$ is even hence $a+c$ is also even: $a\sim c$
  so we verified the reflexivity, symmetry and the transitivity. Conclude

Comment: Wow, these relations seem easier than I thought they'd be.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Bonus question: What are the equivalence classes?

Comment: See now why it is necessary to specify whcih set we are talking about? If $a=\frac12$ were in the set, then $a+a=1$ odd, hence $a\not\sim a$.